# onListItemClick that shows description toast when title is clicked

Tags: java, android, listview

not sure if I am on the correct section, but I needed help for my school project.

Currently I am doing a listview that display the titles of the latest school news, whenever I click any of the title, I want it to toast the description of the selected title correspondingly.

Anyone can help me on it? Thank you

```
    package sp.buzz.rss;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.EventLogTags.Description;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import sp.buzz.rss.tools.*;

public class StringRss extends ListActivity {
    HttpFetch a = new HttpFetch();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        String strOrg = a
                .DownloadText("http://www.sp.edu.sg/wps/wcm/connect/lib-spws/Site-SPWebsite/?srv=cmpnt&source=library&cmpntname=MNU-MobileRSSFeed-SPBuzz-Shine");
        int start = strOrg.indexOf("<title>");
        int end = strOrg.indexOf("</title>");

        int startdesc = strOrg.indexOf("<![CDATA[");
        int enddesc = strOrg.indexOf("]]>");

        int count = 0;

        ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<String> cData = new ArrayList();

        String title = strOrg.substring(start + 7, end);
        String description = strOrg.substring(startdesc + 9, enddesc);
        // Toast.makeText(this, title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// first title
        Toast.makeText(this, description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// first
                                                                    // desc
        // value.add(title);
        // count++;
        cData.add(description);

        String newContent = strOrg.substring(end + 5);

        String newDesc = strOrg.substring(enddesc + 3);

        start = newContent.indexOf("<title>");
        end = newContent.indexOf("</title>");

        startdesc = newDesc.indexOf("<![CDATA[");
        enddesc = newDesc.indexOf("]]>");

        title = newContent.substring(start + 7, end);
        description = newDesc.substring(startdesc + 9, enddesc);

        // Toast.makeText(this, title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// second title
        Toast.makeText(this, description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// second
                                                                    // desc
        value.add(title);
        cData.add(description);
        count++;

        while (true) {

            newContent = newContent.substring(end + 5);
            newDesc = newDesc.substring(enddesc + 3);

            start = newContent.indexOf("<title>");
            end = newContent.indexOf("</title>");

            startdesc = newDesc.indexOf("<![CDATA[");
            enddesc = newDesc.indexOf("]]>");

            if (start == -1 || end == -1) {
                break;
            } else if (startdesc == -1 || enddesc == -1) {
                break;
            }

            title = newContent.substring(start + 7, end);
            description = newDesc.substring(startdesc + 9, enddesc);
            // Toast.makeText(this, description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//
            // for
            count++;
            value.add(title);
            cData.add(description);
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(this, "Value array: " + title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
             * .show();// for debugging
             */
            // Toast.makeText(this, description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//
            // for
            // description

        }

        // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
        String[] names = new String[count];
        String[] desc = new String[count];
        // Create an ArrayAdapter, that will actually make the Strings above
        // appear in the ListView
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

            names[i] = value.get(i);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < desc.length; i++) {

            desc[i] = cData.get(i).replaceAll("</P>", "\n")
                    .replaceAll("<P>", "");
        }

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));

    }

    static String title = "";
    static String desc = "";

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // Get the item that was clicked

        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        title = o.toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Even if this is a school project, read about how to properly parse XML -- `substring`/`indexOf` ain't proper :) It will save you a lot of trouble, maybe already in this project. Here's a good introduction that even deals with RSS, so it should be easy to adapt: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, i had read it before , I tried following it but failed, don't have much time to change now as my deadline is today, thanks.

Comment: Using your example I got this working: String title = ((Header) l.getItemAtPosition(position)).title.toString();

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the method `protected void onListItemClick` with by putting into `onCreate`  the code below. If it isn't working.

```
ListView lv = getListView();

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    String title = ((TextView) view).getText();
    Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}});
```

Also I'm surprised that infinite while loop is working. You should do that part using [threading](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) otherwise the later parts of the method won't be reached.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, i am new to android so pardon me, for now the whole code is working, just that when I click the title in the listview, it will display You selected : (title) , however, I want the toast to be the description corresponding to that title , is it possible to do that? thanks

Comment: I've changed in my code the way you get the title from the listitem. The way you're doing is using the general object to string method whereas this method is specific to getting the text from Android textviews.

Comment: Ahh I still don't really understand, can you add it in from my code? Thanks

Comment: Add `String title = ((TextView) view).getText();` instead of `Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        title = o.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

String title = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();